# Add X-UA-Compatible header

Tags: feature-request

I'm back with another extremely minor thing!

I'd appreciate it if SO could add the following HTTP header to responses:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

The reason I'm asking for this is because it will remove the "Compatibility View" button from the address bar. I can't tell you how many times I've accidentally hit that button when I wanted to click Reload...

Comment: Solution 1: Don't use Internet Exploder. (Oops, my sarcasm is showing.)

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn Sorry, but the sad truth is that as of this writing IE10 is better than (read: less buggy than) Chrome *and* Firefox. Especially Firefox.

Comment: Actually, I somewhat disagree. I find writing for Chrome the easiest, then IE, then Firefox. Still, there's no denying that IE has come a long way.

Comment: I can agree with you there. I guess what I mean to say is that while Chrome does support more than IE, IE "does things right" with what it does support. First example that jumps to mind is that IE can animate gradients, while Chrome cannot.

Comment: True, though I'm pretty sure that's planned for the next version? Still, we're kind of off topic.

Comment: Oh, but IE doesn't support `preserve-3d`, which is a major obstacle to using 3D transforms effectively. Ah well. Open mouth, insert foot. And with that I shall go to bed XD

Comment: Can't you disable it system wide?